# Detecting that file is downloaded, moved and copied

Tags: c++, qt, browser

Is there an idea to handle that file downloaded by any browser or moved or copied from another location (not downloading or moving or coping)?

Safari and Chrome add .(.*)download extension, so download finishing easily handled.
Moving or coping are rapid processes so they can be handled by file size difference after some delay. But it also can be unreliable in some cases like firefox download process.

Also I want cross-platform solution. I use Qt framework.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what your question is, but perhaps [QFileSystemWatcher](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemwatcher.html) is what you are looking for.

From the documentation:

> The QFileSystemWatcher class provides an interface for monitoring
>   files and directories for modifications

Comment: Yes, it handles file modification, but how can I determine that current modification latest in sequence of modification events of current file?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm having trouble understanding you. When you say "current modification latest in sequence of modification events of current file", do you mean "current modification **is** latest in **the** sequence of modification events of **the** current file"?

Comment: Sorry for my english. How can I determine that current modification latest in the sequence of modification events of the current file? QFileSystemWatcher only provides path name where was change. (Signal is emitted when the file at the specified path is modified, renamed or removed from disk.) So signal may be emitted when only part of file stored in observing location, not only when completed.

Comment: QFileSystemWatcher may be helpful if I can determine that modified file is used by another process or it is copied or moved. But I don`t know how to check this.

Comment: Why don't you test it? Write some code, and see what actually happens. I dug up the documentation for you, the rest is your work. Test it, and then implement your solution. Sometimes, you can't avoid writing some code, putting some effort on your own. Don't expect to always find a library function that does everything you need without any effort from you.

Comment: One should not think that I am stupid. I encountered a problem. Asked for possible solutions. There is nothing wrong with that. And yes, I've tried to solve it, but I did not succeed.